# Apache, phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache

Después de instalar `XAMPP` en un `Windows 7 Professional` y ejecutar el servidor local, intento acceder a `phpmyadmin` y me sale esto:

> *¡Acceso prohibido! Usted no tiene permiso para acceder al directorio solicitado. No existe un documento índice, o el directorio está
>   protegido contra lectura. Si usted cree que esto es un error del
>   servidor, por favor comuníqueselo al administrador del portal. Error
>   403 localhost Apache/2.4.35 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0i PHP/7.2.11*

He probado a modificar el archivo **httpd-xamp.conf** como dicen en la gran mayoría de sitios pero sigo sin poder acceder. 
¿Alguna otra solución?

Comment: Solo te pasa con phpmyadmin  o con las web también? Es un problema de configuración del servidor virtual.

Comment: Solo cuando accedo a phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1):

Debes modificar el archivo **httpd.config**. Al final del archivo coloca lo siguiente:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\Fisgo\web">
        Options Indexes 
        AllowOverride All 
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\Fisgo\web
    ServerName localhost
    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Debes reemplazar:

```
Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\Fisgo\web"
```

Por la url donde se encuentre tu archivo index. Lo mismo para DocumentRoot.

Si el error es solo en phpMyAdmin, verifica tu configuracion en **httpd-xamp.conf**
debes tener algo así:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>
```

Revisa que todas las rutas sean correctas. Evidentemente no esta logrando llegar al archivo.

Yo uso el puerto 8888 por que tengo problemas en el bendito win10. Pero lo puedes cambiar por otro. Espero que te sirva para solucionarlo. Saludos!

Comment: Probé a hacer los cambios que me indicas pero sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: en el panel de XAMP te está arrancando el servicio de mySql sin error?

Comment: [![xampp][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isair.png

Comment: YA trataste de reiniciar el servicio?

Comment: @cignius si no arroja error dudo que lo solucione con reiniciar el servicio. Yo insisto en que el problema esta en los archivos de configuración. En alguna ruta incorrecta.

Comment: cada vez que se cambia la configuración en `.conf` hay que reiniciar el servicio

Comment: @aloMalbarez ahh eso si. Pensé que me decías nuevamente!

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo httpd-xampp me pone esta ruta que luego en el explorador no encuentro..

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

El directorio más parecido que es C:\xampp\php o C:\xampp\mysql pero nada de phpMyAdmin. Supongo que será ese el error.